# Android camera take picture permission denial

Tags: android, permissions, camera

Trying to take a picture and it gives me a mistake in the permissions. Because it can not save.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(TAGL,"W onPictureTaken");
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
              Log.d(TAGL, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                 //It shows the error I do not have Permission.
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               Log.d(TAGL, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d(TAGL, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
```

Why do I get out refusal of access?
Tests on Android devices 4.04 and 4,4,2 and the same error; /

Comment: check size of internal or external sd card if your using it in emulator or increase size of sd card so you can store image in it.it may possible due to less space it is not allowing to store image.

Comment: Have 4gb free, i not using emulator

Comment: Log > 334-334/com.example.ciacho.kamdostep D/MyAcitvity﹕ Error creating media file, check storage permissions:

Answer (score 2):

Permission names are case sensitive. Use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```